# TypeScript How to allow free string with auto complete

Tags: typescript, intellisense

Is there a way to allow Free string with auto complete

```
  value:
    | "A"|"B"|"C"
    | string
```

This way IntelliSense can predict/AutoComplete and not give me error if I typed string

Comment: see linked q/a for more info